# Fastest Way to merge XML - Best Architecture

Tags: jaxb

What is the best optimized way to merge multiple xmls have XSD into single xml. We have tried by loading through iterating each one by JAXB. Do we have any better approach other than this to improve performance. Our aim is to merge to 1 xml and enrich and write to xml.

```
for(Part part:invoiceXMLList) {

    File file = new File(new URI(part.getFile()));

     Document document  = (Document) unMarshall.unmarshal(new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file)));

     businessDocument.getDocument().add(document);

  }
```